# Stacking relative position div classes

Tags: html, css

I know this type of question has been asked many times before however through several hours or research/ code fiddling/ frustration, I have still not come across a solution.

**Context:**

My webpage echoes data from a sql table using PHP and to keep a consistent layout I use div classes, when one of the divs is clicked it then changes a session variable. Relative positioning is needed as the number of results does not remain the same and the results are loaded using a while loop, so each div is placed under the previous one. To accomplish this session variable change I have found the following methods use a link - not good for web crawlers, or use a transparent submit button. The transparent submit button will sit on top of each of the divs so the user can't see it, but when clicked it will post the data to a PHP handling page. The problem is that the Z-index does not work on relative positioning.

**My code**

I have create a simple version of my code to show that the divs will not stack on top of each other.

```
<style>
.example1{
position: absolutex;    
width: 400px; 
height: 500px;    
background:green;
font-size: 1.5em; 
z-index: 2;     
}
.example2{
position: relative;    
width: 400px; 
height: 500px;    
background:red;
font-size: 1.5em;  
z-index: 9999; 
}
</style>
<html>
<div class="example1"><p>Example 1</p></div> 
<div class="example2"><p>Example 2</p></div>     
<div class="example1"><p>Example 1</p></div> 
<div class="example2"><p>Example 2</p></div>   
<div class="example1"><p>Example 1</p></div> 
<div class="example2"><p>Example 2</p></div>       
</html>
```

Example 1 (green) would be the SQL output which would be visible ie usernames, example 2 (red) would be the transparent button which I want to be completely on top of example one and be invisible due to being completely opaque. The problem is that example 2 is not stacked on top of example 1 even though it has a higher Z-index.

Comment: Are you looking for absolute positioning?

Comment: This is not answer to your question, but why don't you reduce code using? .example1, .example2 {your css} .example2 {z-index: 3}

Comment: I am trying to find a way of stacking divs which have relative positioning.

Comment: Have you tried setting the top property of the second div to something like -520px?

Comment: I have, and this results in large white gaps where the div would of been if it hadn't of been given a negative top value.

Answer (score 0):

You may be getting tripped up here about how z-index works because you have elements nested within other elements. The stacking context for child elements is resolved within the parent element.

It's hard to say without looking at your original code, but the stacking order is likely something like:

```
parent div - #1
  child p ---- #3
parent div - #2
  child p ---- #4
```

One workaround that is in the spec is to use an opacity value less than 1 to alter the stacking context to something like:

```
parent div - #1 (opacity: .99;)
  child p ---- #1.1
parent div - #2
  child p ---- #3
```

Here are two resources for a more detailed explanation:

http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/#wrapping-up
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context

Comment: I tried changing the opacity, however this did not result in any changes, would you be able to provide an example using the code I provided?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stack div tags one over another, you need to use position absolute (and not relative).

try following code:

you would see overlapping divs, second being on top coz it has higher z-index.

```html
<style>
.example1{
position:absolute;    
width: 400px; 
min-height: 500px;    
max-height: 500px;
font-size: 1.5em; 
z-index: 2;    
}
.example2{
position: absolute;    
width: 400px; 
min-height: 500px;    
max-height: 500px;
font-size: 1.5em;  
z-index: 3;    
}

</style>
<html>
<div class="example1"><p>Example 1</p></div> 
<div class="example2"><p>Example 2</p></div>     
</html>
```

Comment: The problem is that I cannot use position absolute as the divs are outputted underneath each other by the sql ie: div1 (new line) div2 (new line) div 3 (new line).

Answer (score 0):

Hi here's a possible solution, add margin to the div's.

http://codepen.io/dfrierson2/pen/RNoWZe

```
.example1{
position: relative;    
width: 400px; 
height: 500px;    
background:green;
font-size: 1.5em; 
z-index: 2;    
}
.example2{
position: relative;    
width: 400px; 
height: 500px;    
background:red;
font-size: 1.5em;  
z-index: 9999; 
margin: -155px 0 0 100px;
}

<html>
<div class="example1"><p>Example 1</p></div> 
<div class="example2"><p>Example 2</p></div>     
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it results in large white gaps where the div would of been if it hadn't of been given a negative margin.